# Emgu.CV.CvInvoke exception appears

Tags: vb.net-2010

I'm currently using a 64-bit Based Windows 7 OS. I build the program in a x86 platform. Still `Emgu.CV.CvInvoke` appears. oh and I'm using .Net 3.5 framework... One thing all file properties are already in(Copy always)...

Comment: What does "Emgu.CV.CvInvoke appears" mean? In an error message? What is the full message?

Comment: This is the error: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception. Im running it as .vb files....

Comment: This is the Whole Partial Code in .vb file                         Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure
Imports Emgu.Util
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim captures As Capture = New Capture()   <-Error Appears
        Dim img As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = captures.QueryFrame
        PictureBox1.Image = img.ToBitmap()
End Sub
End Class                                                                What I want in this code is to atleast display a windowsform w/ camera.